# Arreglo dinámico en c++

Tags: c++, array, c

Cuando declaro un array *(arreglo)* dinámico, lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
std::vector<int> arreglo; 
int n;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ";
cin>>n;
arreglo.resize(n);
```

Pero tengo una duda al momento de declarar un array que no conozco el tamaño, ejemplo cuando se pide leer por teclado y guardarlo en un array y el programa  termina cuando se ingresa el número `0`, en este caso no conozco cuando veces el usuario ingresará valores al arreglo.

```
std::vector<int> arreglo; // Declaracion del vector.
    int contador=0,numero;  
    arreglo.resize(contador);     
    
    do{
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero (Presione 0 para cerrar): ";
        cin>>numero;
        arreglo[contador]=numero;
        contador++;     
    }while(numero!=0);
```

En el lenguaje `java` existe el `ArrayList`. ¿Existe algo parecido en el lenguaje `c` o `c++`? ¿o cual es la solución para este caso?

Comment: El `vector`  es parecido al ` ArrayList`. El equivalente al  `Add`  en el vector es `push_back`.  `arreglo.push_back(numero)` agrega `numero`  al final  del arreglo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ir agregando los valores uno a uno usando `std::vector::push_back`. Este
metodo toma el valor que le des, y lo copia al final del array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {

    std::vector<int> arreglo;
    do {
        std::cout << "Ingrese un numero (Presione 0 para cerrar): ";
        int temp = 0;
        std::cin >> temp;
        if (temp != 0) {
            arreglo.push_back(temp);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);

    std::cout << "Arreglo:\n";
    for (int i : arreglo) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias  por la explicación Pablo